# How to store items of 3 ListView's in a class

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I have 3 ListView's that are populated like this (well this can be anything, listview is just an example):

this is the first list:

```
LIST1     LIST2     LIST3
A1         
B1
C1
```

If I click on 'A1', list2 will get some items:

```
LIST1     LIST2     LIST3
A1         A2
B1         B2
C1         C2
           D2
           E2
```

Same happens when I click on a  item in list2, then list3 will get some items. I click on A2 this time:

```
LIST1     LIST2     LIST3
A1         A2       A3
B1         B2       B3
C1         C2       
           D2       
           E2
```

So the idea is, how can I make an object(class) that hodls all the listview datas?

If it was only 2 I am thinking like this:

```
public class StoreData
{
   public string ListOne {get;set;}
   public List<string> ListTwo = new List<string>();

   public AddToLostTwo(string text)
   {
      ListTwo.Add(text)
   }
}
```

And I could do in runtime:

```
foreach(string str in ListOne)
{
   List<StoreData> datas = new List<StoreData>();
   StoreData data = new StoreData();

   data.ListOne = str;

   foreach(string str2 in ListTwo)
   {
      data.AddToListTwo(str2);
   }
}
```

So my question is, what is the best way to do this in c# for more than 2 list? Note that I want to later print out on paper something like this:

```
DUMP LISTS
----------
NAME      VALUE      VALUE
A1         A2        A3
                     B3

A1         B2        D3
                     E3
```

Please let me know if I am not clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't really need your own class for this. How about using a `Dictionary` like

```
Dictionary<string, IList<string>> lists = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
```

Then you can add new list like

```
lists.Add("List1");
```

And add items to that list like

```
lists["List1"].Add("Item1");
```

Comment: Can you please give a code to show how to dump data using your code aswell?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StoreData
{
   public string ItemName {get;set;}
   public List<StoreData> ChildList = new List<StoreData>();

   public AddToChilds(StoreData data)
   {
      ChildList.Add(data)
   }
}
```

From my opinion using this class structure will allow you to have as many levels as you want.